# How to get list installed applications with checkbox, sorted with first character identification like these picture?

Tags: android

How to get list installed applications with checkbox, sorted with first character identification like these picture?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such pre-built component in the Android API.

You'll have to build your own using a `ListView`. You can get the installed apps via `PackageManager`'s [`getInstalledApplications()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29).